# capybara - click_link error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I just updated capybara and capybara-webkit from the master branch.   I have restarted my spork server and now any time I call capybara methods (visit or click_link for example) I get an the above error saying 1 argument was passed but 0 were expected.

```
Given /^I have a posting$/ do
  visit "/postings"
  click_link "edit"
end
```

This happens with webkit and selenium.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same issue when updated capybara

Falling back to capybara v2.0.2 worked for me

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as well.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be similar "Ambiguous matches" in `find`. You '/postings' page should have several "edit link"

Suggest to limit the result to first one, like this

```
find("a.edit-link:first").click
```

Ref: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/658

Comment: thank you for your help, but the issue isn't that the element isn't found, its that the method appears to only accept zero arguments...

Comment: The error seems not about "Given" but "Then". What is your full code of this Scenario and full error?

Comment: It happens with my rspec tests now as well, so I was mistaken to put cucumber

Comment: happening for me too and if I use `page.find(".login_links").find("a.btn-login").click_link`
I get `ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`
and `page.find(".login_links").click_link "Login"` results in
`ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`
trying to find whats am missing in it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a wrong version of xpath. In the Gem file it was (1.0.0) and it should be (2.0.0).

Capibara was installed with bundle wich set it corr, but I copied a Gemfile.lock from another project which problably was using outdated versions of gems.